# aws s3 bucket logging - logging destination errors out saying "write not enabled"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 bucket that i want to enable logging for. Let's call this <source-bucket>

I've created another bucket (let's call it <destination-bucket> that is meant to store logs for the above bucket.

I've applied this IAM policy to the <destination-bucket>:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PolicyForS3BucketLogging",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<destination-bucket>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceAccount": "<My-AWS-Account-ID>"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not seem to work because, according to the "AWS Trusted Advisor" tool keeps showing this error for the configuration:

> "Write not enabled"

any ideas on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.